# LINQ to XML -  avoid duplicate entries

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

XML structure:

```
<Emp>
<Employee username="John"/>      
<Employee username="Jason"/>
</Emp>
```

---

I don't want to insert the duplicate attributes to the xml file by following linq to xml query

```
   var newEmployee= XElement.Parse(defaultEmployee.ToString());
   var q = from p in doc.Descendants("Employee")
                        let attr = p.Attribute("username")
                        where attr != null && attr.Value != txtusername.Text 
                        select p;



     foreach(var dupes in q)
      {
         newEmployee.Attribute("username").Value = txtusername.Text ;
         doc.root.Add(newEmployee);
         doc.save(EmployeeFile);
      }
```

I am trying to just add a new employee with out any duplicates,but my code adds duplicates still.

Can some one look at my query and let me know where am I missing the logic ?

Comment: Show the code where you are actually *adding* employees - I just see you overwriting properties

Comment: just added the code where i am actually adding the employees

Comment: Really I can't understand your foreach loop! you will add too many item with same attribute in your loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new employee to your xml there is no loop neccessary, nor parsing any default XML, simply:

```
doc.Root.Add(new XElement("Employee", 
                          new XAttribute("username", txtusername.Text));
```

It's unclear to me what your loop is for, currently you are selecting any employee that has a different user name, and for **each** of those you add a new employee node - that doesn't make much sense, I suspect you want to add the new employee only once.

If you wanted to check on the other hand if the employee with the given user name already exists:

```
bool userExistsAlready = doc.Descendants("Employee")
                            .Any(x=> (string)x.Attribute("username") ==  txtusername.Text);
```

Now you can put a check around the code that adds the new employee:

```
if(!userExistsAlready)
{
  //add new user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this LINQ query you can loop the username attributes, providing a DISTINCT operation:

```
    var q = (from p in newEmployee.Descendants("Employee").Attributes("username")
            select (string)p).Distinct();
```